# On a batch file calling php using Start, how do you log output?

Tags: php, mysql, batch-file

I've got a batch file that did:

```
php-cgi runfile.php >> log.txt
php-cgi runfile2.php >> log.txt
```

Which correctly ran the first and pushed out hte output into the log.txt then called runfile2 and pushed out into the log.txt

But then I changed it so it would start both scripts at the same time on separate processes so the 2nd script wouldn't have to wait; as:

```
start php-cgi runfile.php >> log.txt
start php-cgi runfile2.php >> log.txt
```

Which allows the scripts to correctly run (I think); but the log.txt shows no output.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

**log.bat**

```
start /B dir C:\ >> log1.txt
start /B dir C:\WINDOWS >> log2.txt
```

Comment: Would that be like: start /B php-cgi runfile.php >> log.txt ?

Comment: I assume so. I don't have php-cli so I can't do the proper testing. The `/B` switch is the difference that made it work with my example. Without the switch, it wouldn't create the log files.

Answer (score 1):

It works like a charm. I have a series of :

```
start C:/[path_to_php]/php -f C:/[path_to_scrip1].php > C:/[path_to_log1].txt    
start C:/[path_to_php]/php -f C:/[path_to_scrip2].php > C:/[path_to_log2].txt
```

and it only worked like:

```
start /B C:/[path_to_php]/php -f C:/[path_to_scrip1].php > C:/[path_to_log1].txt
start /B C:/[path_to_php]/php -f C:/[path_to_scrip2].php > C:/[path_to_log2].txt
```

So thanks jnpcl.